# Does docker's Dockerfile "From" download image?

Tags: docker

I followed this article to build multi domain websites
https://carlosvin.github.io/langs/en/posts/reverse-proxy-multidomain-docker/
This is a basic test, very simple. Only three files.

Edit
**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       a.local  
127.0.0.1       b.local
```

**C:\web\multidomain\docker-compose.yml**

```
a:
  build: a
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: a.local
  restart: always

b:
  build: b
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST:  b.local
  restart: always

nginx-proxy:
  image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  restart: always
  privileged: true
```

**C:\web\multidomain\a\Dockerfile**

```
FROM httpd:2.4
RUN echo "<html><body><h1>A</h1>App A works!</body></html>" > /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html
```

**C:\web\multidomain\b\Dockerfile**

```
FROM httpd:2.4
RUN echo "<html><body><h1>B</h1>App B works!</body></html>" > /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html
```

That's all the folders and files. Then:

C:\web\multidomain> docker-compose up -d

It really works. Very very simple.

**But my question is**: There is a line "FROM httpd:2.4". As far as I know, this will download image and use it, isn't it? It should appear in my docker UI > Images section.But my docker no image called httpd:2.4.

If no image called httpd:2.4, Why does it still work?

x x x x x x

```
PS C:\Docker\MultiDomainBasic> docker image ls
REPOSITORY                TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
multidomainbasic_a        latest      fb826b8c2db3   44 seconds ago   144MB
multidomainbasic_b        latest      23b08c2f23ff   45 seconds ago   144MB
sail-8.1/app              latest      4451e0a34f0f   47 hours ago     1.09GB
wordpress                 php7.4      744143078625   2 days ago       605MB
memcached                 alpine      bcea36e93e26   4 days ago       8.21MB
nginx                     alpine      51696c87e77e   4 days ago       23.4MB
jwilder/nginx-proxy       alpine      dfb8bfd11460   5 days ago       42.3MB
mysql                     8.0         667ee8fb158e   10 days ago      521MB
php                       8.1.4-fpm   8c08d993542f   11 days ago      449MB
mailhog/mailhog           latest      4de68494cd0d   20 months ago    392MB
```

Maybe the httpd image is inside multidomainbasic_a, and multidomainbasic_b ?? It is wrapped ?

Comment: In order to extend (and consequently start the build image from the `Dockerfile`), we have to download the base image (and its base image, and its base image, ...). So yes, the image should be there. What does `docker image ls` show? Do you see it there?

Comment: Does "*docker UI*" mean the [Docker Desktop (for Windows)](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/)?

Comment: "docker image ls" > no httpd. 
"docker UI" mean Docker Desktop for windows, yes.

Comment: there is a good tool to inspect you images: try it out. 
https://github.com/wagoodman/dive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dockerfile defines how your new image is created. You aren't running the httpd image, you are running two different images that extended the httpd image:

```
multidomainbasic_a        latest      fb826b8c2db3   44 seconds ago   144MB
multidomainbasic_b        latest      23b08c2f23ff   45 seconds ago   144MB
```

The layers from the httpd image will be found in each of those, with one additional layer created from the RUN step in your Dockerfile.